# How to avoid SecurityError: The operation is insecure. at Firefox when using .mozCaptureStream and MediaRecorder?

Tags: javascript, firefox, mediastream, web-mediarecorder

Given the code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <video width="320" height="280"></video>
  <script>
      const video = document.querySelector("video");
      const src = "https://mirrors.creativecommons.org/movingimages/webm/ScienceCommonsJesseDylan_240p.webm#t=0,10";
      let recorder;
      video.oncanplay = () => {
        video.play(); 
        const mediaStream = video.captureStream();
        recorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStream);
        recorder.ondataavailable = event => 
          console.log(URL.createObjectURL(event.data));
        
        recorder.start();
      }

      video.onpause = () => recorder && recorder.stop();

      video.src = src;
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Chromium browser captures the playback of `<video>` element using `.captureStream()`,  `MediaRecorder()` and logs `Blob URL` of resulting `Blob` at `dataavailable` event of `MediaRecorder` instance.

At Firefox browser which currently implements [`.mozCaptureStream()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/captureStream) an error is thrown `recorder.start()` call `SecurityError: The operation is insecure.` and at `recorder.stop()` call `InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable`.

The errors are apparently due to [Security Considerations](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-fromelement/#security-considerations) of [Media Capture from DOM Elements](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-fromelement/).

How can we avoid the errors described above and achieve same result which Chromium and Chrome browsers implement at Firefox browser?

Comment: That actually sounds like a chrome bug! The video's `crossOrigin` should be set to `"anonymous"` for your code to not throw (note that FF indeed [has a bug about it](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1341016), but at least, they're **too** secure). Also note that you can't expect `mozCaptureStream` to work the same way as `captureStream`,  that's why it's still prefixed/

Comment: @Kaiido No error is thrown at Chromium or Chrome. Composed workaround while continuing to look into solution for concatenating recordings created using `MediaRecorder`. If `crossOrigin` attribute also allows recording of media playback without error, can you post an Answer describing the solution?

Comment: As said in the FF bug I linked to, FF doesn't allow MediaElement served with the correct CORS headers, so as long as it is not fixed, it won't work as a workaround. But what I am saying is that this is a security bug in chrome (I'm letting them now right away about it.) They should not let captureStream be called on a mediaElement served without CORS headers. This goes against all the other CORS security measures (e.g in webAudio or canvas APIs) So you should anyway have the `cross-origin` attribute set on your mediaElement.

Comment: @Kaiido The [specification](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-fromelement/#security-considerations) is not entirely clear about what exactly should occur for cross-origin requests.  Are you also lodging an [issue](https://github.com/w3c/mediacapture-fromelement/issues) at the specification? Can you share link to Chromium bug that you intend to or have filed?

Comment: What is not clear in the specs? It clearly states that it *"MUST be protected from access by the document origin."* Also, how would [this](https://jsfiddle.net/w77z6w90/) not be a bug? And no I can't link to the bug since it is a security one (except if you're a google dev?)

Comment: @Kaiido "protected" is very broad. Also are either a `Blob` or an `ArrayBuffer` a cross origin resource?

Comment: No *"protected"* in this context is very clear. It means that no API should be able to extract the content of the media. Be it in `WebAudioAPI.createMediaElementSource`, in HTMLCanvas `toDataURL` or `toBlob`or 2d `getImageData` *(well the marking should be done in 2d's `drawImage` and webgl's `texImage2D`)* or in MediaRecorder's `start` method. And maybe in others I forget/don't know. All these methods must check that the source is clean and not *protected*. If you really want to write to w3c, then you could propose to include MediaRecorder in there, but their list is obviously not exhaustive.

Comment: And here FF does correctly throws on MediaRecorder's `start` method: https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-record/MediaRecorder.html#mediarecorder-methods

Comment: @Kaiido _"It means that no API should be able to extract the content of the media."_ The [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/mediacapture-fromelement/#security-considerations) does not contain that language, rather states _"How this protection manifests will differ, depending on how the content is accessed."_, which again, is not exactingly clear. Note, the resource at OP is served with `access-control-allow-origin:*` header. Why would you expect for the media content to not be accessible at `MediaRecorder`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154643/discussion-between-kaiido-and-guest271314).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `XMLHttpRequest()` or `fetch()` to get `Blob` representation of  media resource, create a `Blob URL` from `Blob` using `URL.createObjectURL()`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <video width="320" height="280"></video>
  <script>
    (async() => {
      const video = document.querySelector("video");
      const src = "https://mirrors.creativecommons.org/movingimages/webm/ScienceCommonsJesseDylan_240p.webm#t=0,10";
      const url = new URL(src);
      let recorder;
      video.oncanplay = () => {
        // note, audio is not output here
        video.play();
        const mediaStream = video.mozCaptureStream();
        recorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStream);
        recorder.ondataavailable = event =>
          // audio is output at resulting `Blob URL`         
          console.log(URL.createObjectURL(event.data));

        recorder.start();
      }

      video.onpause = () => recorder && recorder.stop();

      const blob = await fetch(url).then(response => response.blob());
      video.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob) + url.hash;

    })();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

alternatively, we can record the media playback of `MediaSource()` set as `.src` of `HTMLMediaElement` by appending an `ArrayBuffer` representation of media resource to the `SourceBuffer` of `MediaSource` instance

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <video width="320" height="280"></video>
  <script>
  (async() => {
  // SecurityError: The operation is insecure.
  //  InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable
  const video = document.querySelector("video");
  const src = "https://mirrors.creativecommons.org/movingimages/webm/ScienceCommonsJesseDylan_240p.webm#t=0,10";
  const url = new URL(src);
  const mediaSource = new MediaSource();
  const mimeCodec = "video/webm;codecs=opus";
  video.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
  mediaSource.onsourceopen = async() => {
    const sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(mimeCodec);
    const mediaBuffer = await fetch(url).then(response => response.arrayBuffer());
    sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(mediaBuffer);
  }
  let recorder;
  video.oncanplay = () => {
    // note, audio is not output here
    video.play(); 
    const mediaStream = video.mozCaptureStream();
    recorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStream);
    recorder.ondataavailable = event => 
      // audio is output at resulting `Blob URL` 
      console.log(URL.createObjectURL(event.data)); 
      
    recorder.start();
  }

  video.ontimeupdate = () => {
    if (Math.floor(video.currentTime) === Number(url.hash.split(",").pop())) {
      video.ontimeupdate = null;
      video.pause();
      mediaSource.endOfStream();
    }
  }

  video.onpause = () => recorder && recorder.stop();

})();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

We could additionally use a helper function to use the same code at each Chromium, Chrome browser and Firefox browser, for example, see [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45365081/2801559) at [captureStream() on dynamically created video element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45363524/capturestream-on-dynamically-created-video-element).